# Open a external file using pdf.js viewer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js viewer for displaying PDF files in webpage. In server side, I have a folder viewer. Inside this folder I have scripts & content folder.

In Server Scripting,

```
// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));
});
```

So if I put [localhost/viewer.html](http://viewer.html) to display the viewer.

To open a file I put [localhost/viewer.html?file=sample.pdf](http://viewer.html?file=sample.pdf). This is working fine if the viewer.html & sample.pdf are in same folder. But I want to load a input file from content folder for viewer.html in scripts folder

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to set up multiple [static middlewares](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) with different root paths:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));
app.use('/content', express.static(__dirname + '/content'));
```

Note that you will have to rewrite your PDF viewer to download files from `http://yourhost/pdf/` instead of `http://yourhost/`.